# In Java, how do do I use Scanner Class to take in multiple inputs in one line without Loop Statements?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

[image]

This is my current code thus far. As you can see, it takes three seperate lines to input the coefficients of the quadratic equation. However, I would like to just input

**a**, **b**, **c** 
in one line. 
The output should be something like the following:

```
Enter the coefficients of a quadratic: 1 -5 6
Equation: 1.0x^2 - 5.0x + 6.0
Roots: 3.0 and 2.0
```

How would I be able to enter **1** **-5** **6** on the same line?

Comment: *"As you can see"* Not everyone can see images. Please post text as text.

Comment: @CaliBaluha. I agree with the above comments that you should paste your code instead of taking a picture. It is all right if you are unfamiliar with formatting as a newcomer. it would be aprreciate if you paste your code.

Comment: How did you get the image to show up without having the link posted?

Comment: It's even simpler if you just copy-paste your code instead of the image. Indent the first line by 4 spaces and it will be formatted as code (or mark it and click the formatting button, `{}`)

Comment: If you copy/paste the code and can't get the formatting correct, one of us can edit it for you.

Comment: @CalliBaluha your code looks fine. Have you tried entering numbers by seperating with one space in same line e.g.- 23 12 24. and press enter after it. scanner will take three doubles.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code as text. Your question is not useful as it is right now. It cannot be searched and it cannot be read by people who are blind or otherwise visually impaired.

Comment: @ANUJSINGH *"It is all right if you are unfamiliar with formatting as a newcomer."* No, it is not. It is a thousand times better to post badly formatted code as text, than to post a screenshot of code. Badly formatted code can easily be edited by us. An image cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have written already does exactly what you want: if you enter all three doubles on one line separated by spaces, then calling `nextDouble` three times will get the three numbers you entered. The reason for this is that Scanner reads tokens separated by any whitespace; they don't have to be separated by newlines. But you do have to press enter for anything to be read, since keyboard input is line-buffered.

If you only enter one or two numbers before pressing enter, it will wait for you to enter the rest on the next line before continuing.

Comment: Alright, it works, I didn't realized spaces can work in that way.